# Why doesn't Swift allow setting value of an optional constant after object initialization?

Tags: swift

The code below creates a compile error saying "error: return from initializer without initializing all stored properties ('self.response' not initialized)"

```
class Question {
    let text: String
    let response: String?
    init(text: String) {
        self.text = text
    }
    func ask() {
        print(text)
    }
}
```

I want to make "response" constant and by the time I initialize, response will be unknown. Besides "return from initializer without initializing all stored properties", why do I have to make it "var"?

Comment: That is not how constants work in Swift. You must set the value before initialization.

Comment: because otherwise it is not ***constant***. You choose: constant or not constant - let or var.

Answer (score 2):

Because Swift tries to make you implement safe code, and having uninitialized stored properties is really not safe, because you or a client of your class may use that constant before it is properly set and the result will be undefined. This is a cause of a lot of bugs that may not be immediately caught.

Moreover, because an optional constant stored property is initialized as having a nil value, if you were able to change its value after initialization you would violate the "constantness" of your constant. That is why you need to declare it as a var.

Answer (score 1):

Optional variables / properties are automatically set to `nil` by definition if no initial value is provided in the declaration line.

An optional constant is stuck to `nil` which makes no sense...

Therefore the compiler doesn't let you declare an optional constant this way.