# Swift: let is uninitialized but var gets initialized. Why?

Tags: swift

I'm using playgrounds to learn Swift and I noticed something strange when trying to set optionals on var and let. Below is the code with output:

```
var num1: Int?
print(num1) //Output: "nil\n"

let num2: Int?
print(num2) //Output: Error: Constant num2 used before initialized
```

I do not understand why 'var' gets initialized with nil and 'let' is uninitialized when made optional.

Comment: My guess is language set `nil` as default value when you create `var` but do not do this when you declare `let`

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34969234/why-doesnt-swift-allow-setting-value-of-an-optional-constant-after-object-initi.

Comment: @Hamish: That is what I was looking for. How do you find the (correct) duplicates so quickly?

Comment: @MartinR Combination of keeping them favourited and google searches :) I sometimes remember the name of the person who answered / asked the question – which helps the search.

Answer (score 0):

var is variable, you can declare it without initialisation. But let is constant, you should initialise it’s value, i.e.

```
    var num1: Int?
    print(num1) //Output: "nil\n"

    let num2: Int = 20
    print(num2)
```

Comment: You can also visit here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002092/what-is-the-difference-between-let-and-var-in-swift

Comment: That is not quite correct (or misleading). You must assign a value to a constant before it is used, but not necessarily in its declaration. Example: `let num2: Int; num2 = 5 ; print(num2)`